# Java 8 filter to stream list return by method

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm still learning `java8`, but here's what I'm basically trying to do.  I have this method here that I'd like to convert into a stream.

```java
public void checkCustomers() {

  List<Student> students = studentRegistry.getAllStudents();
  List<Student> mathStudents = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Customer> studentCustomers = new ArrayList<>();

  for (Student student : students) {
       if (!student.getAll().contains(Classes.MATH101)) {
           mathStudents.add(student);
       }
   }

   for (Student student : mathStudents){
       List<Customer> tempStudentCustomers = getCustomers(student.getId());
       studentCustomers.addAll(tempStudentCustomers);
   }

   cancelCustomers(studentCustomers);
}
```

I've been working on this for a while and having a ton of issues. I'm basically trying to do something like this:

```
cancelCustomers(studentRegistry.getAllStudents().stream()
               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
               .filter(p -> (p.getAll().contains(Classes.MATH101)))
               .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I know this doesn't work for a lot of reasons, but every time I fix one of them, a different issue seems to pop up.  I can share other code if necessary, but the main bit of what I'm trying to do is here.

Comment: ‍‍`cancelCustomers(studentRegistry.getAllStudents().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull). filter(p -> ( p.getAll().contains(Classes.MATH101))). .map(s->getCustomers(s.getId())).collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: It seems to me that the issues are already in the original code, before you even started to convert it the Stream code. Are you aware that the loop `for (Student student : mathStudents) { studentCustomers = getCustomers(student.getId()); }` will repeatedly overwrite the `studentCustomers` variable and hence, only keep that last value?

Comment: Does method `getCustomers` return a collection of `Student` instances and do you imply to collect _all_ student customers and then cancel them?  Also the logic of defining `mathStudents` seems to be inverted: why the students whose classes do NOT contain `Math101` are added to `mathStudents`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```java
studentRegistry.getAllStudents().stream().
               filter(Objects::nonNull).
               filter(p -> ( p.getAll().contains(Classes.MATH101))).
               map(std -> getCustomers(std.getId())). // Maps each student to List<Customer>...
               collect(Collectors.toList())
```

The above stream code snippet will return you a `List` of `Lists`. Of this form: `List<List<Customer>>`.

If you want to join this list of lists into a list which contains all the sub-elements (customers), add the following to your code:

```java
List<Customer> studentCustomers = studentRegistry.getAllStudents().stream().
               filter(Objects::nonNull).
               filter(p -> ( p.getAll().contains(Classes.MATH101))).
               map(std -> getCustomers(std.getId())). 
               flatMap(List::stream). // this here does the magic
               collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But I think your code from your function has problems also...

This part for example

```java
List<Customer> studentCustomers = new ArrayList<>();


for (Student student : mathStudents){
   studentCustomers = getCustomers(student.getId()); //  You update the array of studentCustomers, but you never do anything with it.
   // You only cancel the customers of the last found mathStudent...
}

cancelCustomers(studentCustomers); // Is this the right logic?
```

Comment: Thank you Renis1235.  This is exactly what I needed.  The second example, using flatMap worked great.  As for your comments, `getCustomers(long student)` returns an ArrayList of all customers belonging to a specific student.  `cancelCustomers`, in this instance, is expected to cancel every customer for each student not in Math101.  I see where the logic is wrong.  I should have a `tempStudentCustomers`, assign the `getCustomers` and then `studentCustomers.add(tempStudentCustomers)`

Answer (score 0):

Below should work fine.

```
cancelCustomers(studentRegistrey.getAllStudents().stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(student -> !student.getAll().contains(Classes.MATH101))
                .map(student -> getCustomers(student.getId())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I'm not sure whether you want to keep the math students or discard them. If you want to retain maths only students, remove the `!` from filter method.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```java
public void checkCustomers() {
    studentRegistry.getAllStudents().stream()
                   .filter(student -> !student.getAll().contains(Classes.MATH101))
                   .map(mathStudent -> getCustomers(mathStudent.getId()))
                   .forEach(this::cancelCustomers);
}
```

Or in case you want to call `cancelCustomers()` one time:

```java
public void checkCustomers() {
    cancelCustomers(studentRegistry.getAllStudents().stream()
                                   .filter(student -> !student.getAll().contains(Classes.MATH101))
                                   .map(mathStudent -> getCustomers(mathStudent.getId()))
                                   .flatMap(List::stream)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```